# Nginx configuration - Can't make connection for separate 3 individual servers (Client/API/DB)

Tags: reactjs, nginx, server

**What I am trying to do**

I'm trying to setup connection between 3 individual servers (Client, API, and mySQL) by creating 3 VMs locally with following ip addresses and simple testing React/Node code below.

```
Client with React JS    192.168.56.103    Port  3000
API with Node JS        192.168.56.104    Port  4000
mySQL                   192.168.56.105
```

**Problem**

The API server can connect to mySQL server successfully. However, Client server seems to unable connect to API server. I got the following error

> GET http://192.168.56.103:3000/192.168.56.104/products 404 (Not Found)

and this error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I'm trying to solve this issue for almost a day now. Please help.

**Nginx Configuration**

I am using Nginx as web server on both Client and API server. Here is Client Nginx configuration.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /sample_application/sample_front/public;
        index index.html ;

        server_name _;
        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Here is API Nginx configuration.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location /products {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```

**React/Node code**

The following is part of React js code. I have already test this out locally on localhost (without VMs) They all works perfectly fine. But when on VM it shows only static information but data from the back-end and database.

```
getProducts = _ => {
    fetch(BACK_URL + '/products')
    //fetch(BACK_URL + ':' +BACK_PORT + '/products')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({ products: response.data }))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }

  addProduct = _ => {
    const { product } = this.state;
    fetch(BACK_URL + '/products/add?name=' + product.name)
    //fetch(BACK_URL + ':' +BACK_PORT + '/products/add?name=' + product.name)
      .then(this.getProducts)
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }
```

The following is part of Node js code. The console log as 'Connected success'. Accessing 192.168.56.104:4000, data from the database display successfully.

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw(err);
      console.log("Connected success");
  });

app.use(cors());

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    connection.query(SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else {
            return res.json({
                data: results
            })
        }
    });
});

app.listen(BACK_URL.BACK_PORT, () => {
    console.log('Back-end listening on port' + ' ' + BACK_URL.BACK_PORT)
});
```

**Note**

I have test React/Node/mySQL locally runing npm start and node command on localhost. Opening through browser, they work perfectly.

**My Knowledge.**

New to both coding and server deployment.

Comment: Unusual set up for a personal project, but nevertheless the problem is in the GET request URL. If the client is trying to access the API, it shouldn't be `http://192.168.56.103:3000/192.168.56.104/products`, instead it should be:  `http://192.168.56.104:4000/products`. You'll need to reconfigure the `fetch` base url.

Comment: @MattCarlotta Can you guide a bit more? I have tried changing the fetch to `fetch(BACK_URL + ':' +BACK_PORT + '/products')`. The previous GET error `http://192.168.56.103:3000/192.168.56.104/products` has gone. But got a new one `TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from 192.168.56.104:4000/products`

Comment: Download Postman:https://www.getpostman.com/downloads and make a `GET` request to the API. Also, install and use Morgan: https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan as express middleware (`app.use(morgan('tiny')`) on your API. The combination of the two will tell you if the request makes it to your server and whether or not the request is routing correctly. Since there are many variables at play here, try to eliminate as many as possible: 1.) Does the request reach the API? 2.) Does the API handle the request correctly? 3.) Does the API respond correctly? 4.) Does the client receive the API response?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Just add http:// before the ipaddress